# sum and minus array function php

Tags: php, arrays, math

What is the easiest way to achieve:

```
a => 1, b =>  0, c=> 3
a => 0, b => 10, c=> 1
```

**Sum**

```
a => 1, b =>10, c=>4
```

and

**Minus**

```
a => -1, b=> 10, c=> -2
```

I hope my examples make it clear... If you have any questions please leave a comment

Comment: for the minus part, i think u refer to (a*-1)-(a*-1)... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $sum = $minus = 0;
 foreach ($arrays as $key=>$val)
 {
   $sum   += $val;
   $minus -= ($val*-1);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sum:

```
$array1 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 0, 'c' => 3);
$array2 = array('a' => 0, 'b' => 10, 'c' => 1);

$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
  $result[$key] = $value + $array2[$key];
```

You can implement the difference part similarly.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add orsubstarct the values with same key.

Try to write function with array_walk

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

or put in a loop and add or substarct based on key.